# Annotate Subplots in a Figure with A, B, C

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, plot-annotations

When submitting papers to scientific journals one quite frequently needs to enumerate the different subplots of a figure with A, B, ... .

[image]

This sounds like a very common problem and I was trying to find an elegant way to do that automatically with matplotlib, but I was surprised to find nothing on it. But maybe I am not using the right search terms. Ideally, I am searching for a way to annotate such that the letters stay in place relative to the subplot if the figure is resized or the subplot is moved via `fig.subplots_adjust`, `fig.tight_layout`, or similar.

Any help or solution will appreciated.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you want the annotation relative to the subplot then plotting it using `ax.text` seems the most convenient way to me.

Consider something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import string

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(8,8))
axs = axs.flat

for n, ax in enumerate(axs):
    
    ax.imshow(np.random.randn(10,10), interpolation='none')    
    ax.text(-0.1, 1.1, string.ascii_uppercase[n], transform=ax.transAxes, 
            size=20, weight='bold')
```

[image]

edit:

With the new [plt.subplot_mosiac](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic), the example above can be written as. Perhaps slightly more elagant. And consider adding [constrained_layout=True](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html).

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplot_mosaic("AB;CD", figsize=(10,10))

for n, (key, ax) in enumerate(axs.items()):

    ax.imshow(np.random.randn(10,10), interpolation='none')    
    ax.text(-0.1, 1.1, key, transform=ax.transAxes, 
            size=20, weight='bold')
```

Comment: I knew there had to be an elegant way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Marked as duplicate to a question I answered.  I acknowledge the conflict of interest, but went by question priority.  Let me know if you feel aggrieved.

Comment: No, no problem at all. Go ahead.

Comment: Particularly like the string.ascii_uppercase[n] trick!