# Remove Letter Labels on Holoviews Figures with Matplotlib Backend

Tags: python, holoviews

When I create a Holoviews figure of two or more plots with a Matplotlib backend, I get each figure labeled with a letter (A, B, etc). For example:

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('matplotlib')

test = hv.Points(np.random.random(20).reshape(-1, 2)) + \
    hv.Points(np.random.random(20).reshape(-1, 2))

test
```

(My low reputation won't let me post an image of the output here, but here's another example from the [Holoviews Documentation](http://holoviews.org/reference/containers/matplotlib/Layout.html#matplotlib-gallery-layout).)

I imagine the idea for these being here is more accurate labeling for static figures in published papers, but I don't need it for my use case. Given the styling looks a lot like it would in [pure Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543978/matplotlib-annotate-subplots-in-a-figure-with-a-b-c), I imagine this is a conscious choice hidden in source code, but I haven't been able to find it or figure out how to turn it off. Is there a way to toggle these letter labels on and off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use the `sublabel_format` option:

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('matplotlib')

test = hv.Points(np.random.random(20).reshape(-1, 2)) + \
       hv.Points(np.random.random(20).reshape(-1, 2))

test.opts(sublabel_format="")
```

Or, if you want to turn it off for *everything*, you can add these lines to the top of your notebook or to your ~/.holoviews.rc file:

```
from holoviews.plotting.mpl import MPLPlot
MPLPlot.sublabel_format=""
```