# Seaborn plot with multiple subplots and multiple y axis for each one

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot, twinx

When plotting with `twinx` how can multiple subplots be used?

```
%pylab inline
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04'], 'category':['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], 'foo':[10, 15, 8, 13], 'bar':[12, 8, 5, 18]})
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])

ax = sns.lineplot(x='dt', y='foo', data=df, hue='category')
ax.set_ylabel('asdf', fontsize=28)
ax.plot([], '-g', label = 'other axis in legend')
plt.legend(fontsize='x-large')
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles[1:], labels=labels[1:], fontsize='large', loc='lower left')
plt.xticks(rotation=90, horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=28)
plt.xlabel('')
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2 = sns.lineplot(x='dt', y='bar', data=df, ax=ax2, color='green')
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
ax2.plot([], '-g', label = 'other axis in legend')
ax2.set_ylabel('ratio', fontsize=28)

plt.axvline(x=np.datetime64('2020-01-02'),color='k', linestyle='--', lw=4)
plt.text(x=np.datetime64('2020-01-02'), y=10, s=' foo-the-bar  ', fontsize=28, horizontalalignment='left')
plt.show()


d2 = pd.DataFrame({'dt':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04'], 'category':['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'],'foo':[11, 16, 8, 14], 'bar':[11, 7, 4, 17]})
d2['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(d2['dt'])

ax = sns.lineplot(x='dt', y='foo', data=d2, hue='category')
ax.set_ylabel('something else', fontsize=28)
ax.plot([], '-g', label = 'other axis in legend')
plt.legend(fontsize='x-large')
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles[1:], labels=labels[1:], fontsize='large', loc='lower left')
plt.xticks(rotation=90, horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=28)
plt.xlabel('')
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
plt.axvline(x=np.datetime64('2020-01-02'),color='k', linestyle='--', lw=4)
plt.text(x=np.datetime64('2020-01-02'), y=10, s=' foo-the-bar  ', fontsize=28, horizontalalignment='left')


ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2 = sns.lineplot(x='dt', y='bar', data=d2, ax=ax2, color='green')
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
ax2.plot([], '-g', label = 'other axis in legend')
ax2.set_ylabel('ratio', fontsize=28)
plt.show()
```

It is more or less nice. But when adding in subplots to combine multiple measurements into a single figure sharing the x-axis (i.e. saving space and writing the dates over and over) the following fails to work and completely distorts the plot

```
ax0 = plt.subplot(211)
ax2 = ax0.twinx()
ax3 = plt.subplot(212)
ax4 = ax3.twinx()

ax = sns.lineplot(x='dt', y='foo', data=df, hue='category', ax=ax0)
ax.set_ylabel('asdf', fontsize=28)
ax.plot([], '-g', label = 'other axis in legend')
plt.legend(fontsize='x-large')
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles[1:], labels=labels[1:], fontsize='large', loc='lower left')
plt.xticks(rotation=90, horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=28)
plt.xlabel('')
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
plt.axvline(x=np.datetime64('2020-01-02'),color='k', linestyle='--', lw=4)
plt.text(x=np.datetime64('2020-01-02'), y=10, s=' foo-the-bar  ', fontsize=28, horizontalalignment='left')


#ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2 = sns.lineplot(x='dt', y='bar', data=df, ax=ax2, color='green')
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
ax2.plot([], '-g', label = 'other axis in legend')
ax2.set_ylabel('ratio', fontsize=28)
plt.show()


# TODO second plot is missing
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on how the second code "fails to work and completely distorts the plot"? It looks fine to me.

Comment: The text labels are plotted way out of the plot  (but only for the subplot version), and the vertical lines are lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems always arise when trying to mix [the object-oriented syntax and the pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html#a-note-on-the-object-oriented-api-vs-pyplot) interface.

[pyplot functions](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html) (`plt.XXX`) only affect the *current* axes (generally the latest created, in your case `ax4`). When you have several axes, it is generally much better to use the OO functions so that there is no ambiguity about which axes you are working on.

Additionally, you might want to through a [`tight_layout()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/tight_layout_api.html?highlight=tight_layout#module-matplotlib.tight_layout) at the end of your code to automatically adjust the position of your axes to give enough room for your labels

```
plt.figure()
ax0 = plt.subplot(211)
ax2 = ax0.twinx()
ax3 = plt.subplot(212)
ax4 = ax3.twinx()

ax = sns.lineplot(x='dt', y='foo', data=df, hue='category', ax=ax0)
ax.set_ylabel('asdf', fontsize=28)
ax.plot([], '-g', label = 'other axis in legend')
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles[1:], labels=labels[1:], fontsize='large', loc='lower left')
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90, horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=28)
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=16)
ax.axvline(x=np.datetime64('2020-01-02'),color='k', linestyle='--', lw=4)
ax.text(x=np.datetime64('2020-01-02'), y=10, s=' foo-the-bar  ', fontsize=28, horizontalalignment='left')


#ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2 = sns.lineplot(x='dt', y='bar', data=df, ax=ax2, color='green')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=16)
ax2.plot([], '-g', label = 'other axis in legend')
ax2.set_ylabel('ratio', fontsize=28)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Really cool. How can I also 1) set `sharex` to true and name the sub plots?

Comment: You can use `ax3 = plt.subplot(212, sharex=ax0)` to share the xaxis. Not sure what you mean by "name the subplots", maybe you want to put a title on top? `ax0.set_title("top subplot")`

Comment: I figured out to name them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543978/matplotlib-annotate-subplots-in-a-figure-with-a-b-c however 1) is still unsolved for me. I want to shar the x axis, but your solution (I have it in my code already) does not seem to change anything and the x axis is plotted 2x.

Comment: `sharex` only ensures that the limits stay in sync between the two axes. If you want to hide one set of labels, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209467/matplotlib-share-x-axis-but-dont-show-x-axis-tick-labels-for-both-just-one

Comment: One question though: `ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=16)` deletes the y axis labels. How can this be prevented? I just want to increase the font size.

Comment: You're right, this line does not work as intended. Use [`Axes.tick_params()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) instead. I've corrected my code